# Finding all cycles with weight > 0 in a special directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle

I'm looking for an algorithm to find all cycles with a total weight of all its edges that is greater than 0. I heard that this problem is NP-complete, but since I want to solve this for a special graph that always looks more or less the same, I hope there is an easier method.

My graph looks like this:

[image]

It always is a square of `n * n` vertices and edges between all horizontally and vertically adjacent vertices. There are just two possible weights, for black edges -1 and for the green ones its +1.

For this example the cycles I'm looking for would be:

- 7; 12; 17; 18; 19; 14; 13; 8; 7   => weight: +1
- 7; 12; 13; 8; 7   => weight: +1
- 7; 8; 7   => weight: +2
- 18; 23; 24; 19; 18   => weight: +1
- 7; 12; 17; 18; 23; 24; 19; 14; 13; 8; 7 weight:   => +2

---

What would be an efficient algorithm for this task? It should be quite fast, because I also want to do this for graphs with `n = 25 => 625` vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a basic cycle detection with a DFS and some modifications to it :

- When you encounter a node, if you're already visiting this same node, you know that you're in a cycle so you check if the weight is positive, if so just go through the cycle again to keep the path in memory.
- If the node you're visiting has already been seen just stop here.
- Then recursively visit the node's neighbour.

The pseudo-code might look like this :

```
dfs(node, weight):
     if state[node] is "in progress" AND weight > 0
         // This is a cycle we want
         Keep in memory the path (just go throught the cycle once more)
     if state[node] is "visited"
         Stop

     state[node] = "in progress"
     For each neighbour
         dfs(neighbour, weight + edge_weight)
     state[node] = "visited"
```

If you do that for each starting node, you should get a complexity in time of approximately O(N * M) with N the number of vertices and M the number of edges.

Hope this helps !

EDIT : forgot to update the state

Comment: OK, but I think your algorithm just detects one cycle. I want to find all of them.

Comment: No this algorithm should detect all of them, you just need as I said to call this function for each starting node to get everything ;)